# Heating Pan & Oil

Tags: oil

Virgin question -- be gentle. Wasn't able to find answer in database.

I've seen recipes that say heat pan and then add oil and recipes that say add oil to pan and heat both together.

Does it matter? Do the different oil-heating strategies achieve different results?If so, why?

Thanks,

Stu

Comment: When your question is a duplicate of one with that many upvotes, no need to feel bad! If there's anything specific you were curious about that isn't covered there, please feel free to ask a new question about just that aspect.

Comment: It also happens to be an old question and answer so sometimes unless your search string is a good match, the results show up too far down to be valuable.

Comment: I find SE's search engine a bit lacking, but the search string: `heat pan oil site:cooking.stackexchange.com` in Google much more effective (it's the top result) That's an SE pro tip right there: don't use SE to search lol

Comment: Thanks everyone! The old post answered my question. Every search engine has its quirks, I need to spend some time figuring out SEs.